# Exit Undef cowboy:start_http

Tags: erlang, cowboy

When I try to upgrade (removing deps/cowboy and deps/cowlib), make and run it again to get the latest COWBOY Web Server, then it failed by cowby:start_http undefined

```
application: cowboy_test
    exited: {bad_return,
             {{cowboy_test_app,start,[normal,[]]},
              {'EXIT',
               {undef,
                [{cowboy,start_http,
                  [my_http_listener,100,
                   [{port,8080}],
                   [{env,[{dispatch,[{'_',[],[{[],[],hello_handler,[]}]}]}]}]],
                  []},
                 {cowboy_test_app,start,2,
                  [{file,"src/cowboy_test_app.erl"},{line,13}]},
                 {application_master,start_it_old,4,
                  [{file,"application_master.erl"},{line,273}]}]}}}}
```

Any recommendation please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please see the answer on [this](https://github.com/ninenines/cowboy/issues/975) issue, dont use the master branch of CowBoy as it contains breaking changes. I switched back to 2.0.0-pre.3 in my own project and it works for my application.

My Makefile:

```
PROJECT = webserver
DEPS = cowboy erlydtl
dep_cowboy = git https://github.com/ninenines/cowboy 2.0.0-pre.3
include erlang.mk
```

Then I build using 'make' and start it with './_rel/webserver/bin/webserver console' (change 'webserver' with your own application name and do not start it with 'make run').